# How to link with Benchmark in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I created a simple file

benchmark.ml:

```
open Benchmark ;;

print_string "It works!"; print_newline() ;;
```

Then I tried to build it with the following contents of my Makefile

```
# put here the names of your source files (in the right order)
SOURCES = benchmark.ml

# the name of the resulting executable
RESULT  = benchmark

# generate type information (.annot files)
ANNOTATE = yes

# make target (see manual) : byte-code, debug-code, native-code, ...
all: debug-code

include OCamlMakefile
```

But I get the error:

```
Unbound module Benchmark
```

What should I do to fix it? I tried using `INCDIRS` or `PACKS` but to no avail.

Comment: if you use another name for your program ? I manage to compile with corebuild -pkg benchmark yourcode.native only if change the name of your program. I did not try with OcamlMakefile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PACKS is the right solution.

Just don't name your file `benchmark.ml`, if you intend to use another module, that is already called `Benchmark`.